# I use godaddy hosting and want to have asp.net membership database. How many user accounts will bring the database size to 200 MB?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-membership

I user godaddy hosting and they allow database use upto 200 mb. I plan to have a website with many user account and will use asp.net membership database for managing these accounts. How many user accounts will eat up 200 MB space. If someone can give an exact figure then it would be easy to decide if i have to plan on my budget to buy more database space.

Comment: This all depends on what you are storing in the database, and how you define many accounts. There is no way anyone can answer this question as presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a quick scientific and exact (not) calculation on a certain database, I came up with a bit less than two kilobytes per user (with no roles), including indexes. That is, if you only care about the ASP.NET membership tables, of course.

This would bring your maximum user count somewhere near one hundred thousand users. I doubt you'll get that many users in quite a while, so I wouldn't concern myself with the space the few rows in the membership tables will take.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i trust the figure you gave me.

Comment: But you shouldn't because it depends on your actual database design not somebody else's design. Only you can calculate how many bytes must be reserved for a user depending on what data you are storing.

Comment: @HLGEM: The ASP.NET membership tables are a part of ASP.NET and shouldn't change much between environments, except maybe due to version differences. Of course the data size changes based on your users (name lengths and whatnot), but I used a sample of production data for a rough estimate. Personally I think this question is silly, because most likely non-user account data will end up taking the most space.

Comment: With all due respect to you guys, i just wanted to have a rough estimate, a very quick and dirty one. I believe we all people share this community and at least i have gained from it a lot. Its not about being silly or not, its about consulting all you learned people in case of a doubt. I had one and i posted, thanks for all your brain storming.